# I'm looking for a very sensitive photodiode

Tags: photodiode, light-sensor

I'm working with a custom board that has a simple input to detect a closed switch, and I'm hoping to use it as a light sensor.  I was thinking of just attaching a simple photodiode (Like this one: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/excelitas-technologies/VTP9812FH/5885875), and that works, but it requires a pretty high level of light to switch.  I'm hoping there's an option with a much higher sensitivity, so the circuit would be open when in pitch blackness, but closed when there's almost any amount of ambient light.  Any recommendations on an alternate component, or a more complicated circuit that I could rig up to accomplish that?

Comment: All photodiodes have a dark current, and the physical properties of a silicon diode cannot be changed. You would need to amplify the signal. Do you have access to the power supply?

Comment: OK, an LDR might do it, but basically what works and what does not depends on what is the input circuitry of your board, which is unknown, so we can't suggest what works based on this info. On the other hand, asking what to buy and places where to buy from are off-topic.

Comment: The device is powered by a 3.9V primary cell; I could use that to power some additional circuitry with a little jury rigging, if that's what it takes to make something work.

Comment: I would buy an ambient light sensor, which is essentially a photo detector and an amplifier that is calibrated to tell you how light/dark it is. You can even get them with digital interfaces for easy integration with a microcontroller. You could build your own but if you have no idea how to do that I wouldn't bother.

Comment: VTP9812 [datasheet here](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Excelitas%20PDFs/VTP9812FH.pdf). Graphs on page 3 show sensitivity. You need an amplifier that takes less than 1 uA input and converts it to a suitable output for your board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum quantum efficiency of a photodiode is 1 electron per incident photon. This sets a limit on the maximum responsivity of a photodiode at any given wavelength (because the energy per photon depends on the wavelength).

To get a stronger response in your system, you can use a *transimpedance amplifier* or TIA with your photodiode.

Or, if the signals you're receiving are fairly slow you can use a phototransistor instead of a photodiode.

Or, for faster signals you can use an *avalanche photodiode* or APD. APD's use the avalanche effect to produce internal gain and produce an effective quantum efficiency greater than 1. But they require adding a precision high voltage (20-400 V) bias source to your system.

Note:

In optoelectronics, *responsivity* refers to the amplitude of the response of a receiver, measured in amps per watt of input optical power.

*Sensitivity* refers to the minimum input power required to be detectable compared to the receiver noise. The sensitivity of your receiver likely depends more on the noise performance of your transimpedance amplifier or sampling circuit than on the photodiode itself (although the photodiode capacitance affects the receiving circuit noise bandwidth).

Comment: Thanks, this helped point me in a useful direction.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need speed, a phototransistor is easier and has much higher output. Most reflective and photo-interruptor modules use phototransistors similar to [this](https://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/APECVA3010P3BT.pdf) one because they are sensitive and fast enough to detect mechanical motion easily at more than 10,000 RPM (for example).  The one I linked specifies 15us rise/fall time with 1K, but so if you use a 10K-100K load they will be 10-100x more sensitive but more like 150us-1.5ms, which is still plenty fast enough for some applications.

There are also linear (with defined output) and digital sensors (especially for sensing ambient light) such as [this](https://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS86-2014-0006/LTR-329ALS-01_DS_V1.pdf) one from Liteon. I just picked the cheapest one in stock that met a couple criteria, you should do a detailed search for something that meets your unique requirements if you decide to go that way (this is not a recommendation).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the suggestions.